# List with object Total of same id in Java

Tags: java

```
List<Item> list= new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(new Item("a", 1));
list.add(new Item("b", 2));
list.add(new Item("a", 3));
list.add(new Item("c", 10));
list.add(new Item("c", 50));
```

result

```
Sum of a = 4;
Sum of b = 2;
Sum of c = 60;
```

How to Total of same key in this example, i try so many times but not able to total of that so please help me to solve this.

Comment: You can't have map with same keys. In this case for key 'a' you will have value 3 and for key 'c' you will have value 50. When you are doing the put for same key twice, the second time you are rewriting the value. That is why you can't do this.

Comment: The data structure you might be looking for is `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 1):

A [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) maintains the uniqueness of keys i.e. when you will try to add an element with the existing key, the old value will be replaced with the new one. You can understand it with your own example given below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>();
        m1.put("a", 1);
        m1.put("b", 2);
        m1.put("a", 3);
        m1.put("c", 10);
        m1.put("c", 50);
        System.out.println(m1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{a=3, b=2, c=50}
```

As you can see, `3` has replaced `1` because it has been put in the key using the same key, `a`.

If you have a requirement to keep both `3` and `1` with the same key/id, you can implement your custom type something like:

```
class Item {
    private String id;
    private int val;
    //Constructors, getters and setters 
}
```

And then, add the instances of `Item` to a `List` e.g.

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(new Item("a", 1));
list.add(new Item("b", 2));
list.add(new Item("a", 3));
list.add(new Item("c", 10));
list.add(new Item("c", 50));
```

Finally, you can group the items on `id` and calculate the sum as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Item {
    private String id;
    private int val;

    public Item(String id, int val) {
        this.id = id;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [id=" + id + ", val=" + val + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
        list.add(new Item("a", 1));
        list.add(new Item("b", 2));
        list.add(new Item("a", 3));
        list.add(new Item("c", 10));
        list.add(new Item("c", 50));

        list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.getId(), Collectors.summingInt(item -> item.getVal())))
                .forEach((id, sumVal) -> System.out.println("Sum of " + id + " = " + sumVal));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Sum of a = 4
Sum of b = 2
Sum of c = 60
```

Comment: you are right MR, Thank you for sharing kind knowledge about Map Thank You very much.

Comment: @atomandroid -  You are most welcome.

Comment: where you write list.strem().collect that is not working in android

Comment: I've posted a tested code. You need to import `java.util.stream.Collectors`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: i import but lambda expressions are not supported